# Keep one consistent font spacing and face in Evernote

Tags: evernote, fonts

How do I get Evernote to display consistent font spacing and typefaces when viewing the app?

I basically only use the Windows downloaded app and the iPhone app and never actually change the font but it seems like I end up with a couple different fonts and spacing issues.

I assume this is some kind of cross platform issue?

Here's a shot of what it looks like:

> [image: example shot of font variance][1]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have set Arial to my default font on the Windows desktop version of Evernote, but the font changes when I access those notes on my iPhone or iPad. I don't believe Arial is a standard font on iOS.

Comment: @tony - so you are still having this issue then?

Comment: Long shot here, but it might have to do with the fact that line breaks are different on Windows and Mac (iOS). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems) for clarifications.

Comment: @Alex - I don't think that's it, even a single line entry has this issue

Comment: This happens when you copy/paste or when you type in the text?

Comment: From [this](http://forum.evernote.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=9008) thread, it seems that it's a known bug and it has to do with the Windows client text editor.

Comment: Although Evernote has a web implementation, you say you're not using it. So maybe this belongs on Superuser?

Answer (score 2):

The text editor in the Evernote client is low quality and buggy (at least on Windows, I haven't tried any of the others). It frequently gets itself in a mess. You could try re-pasting the text without formatting. Try this in the Windows client:

1. Inside a note, select all: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.
2. Cut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.
3. Paste without formatting: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using a font that does not exist on one of the platforms.
Case in point: the Helvetica font (and its derivatives) is widely used on the Mac and iPhone, but does not exist in Windows by default (you can add it for free if you like it). Therefore, the Windows client will attempt to substitute it with (what it deems) the closest/default-est font.

My recommendation: switch to Arial font. It's widely used on many platforms. I currently use Evernote on: Mac, Windows, iPad, Android and iPhone - no issues noted so far.